# Unable to get non-empty string from PhoneStateListener::onCallStateChanged

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Source:

```
listener = new PhoneStateListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }

    };

    ((TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).listen(listener , PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE )
```

Hi,
I am using this code, with `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission, to get toast message including number of started call. My problem is that incomingNumber is empty, it doest not matter if call is outgoing or incomming, toast appear, but empty.
I have seen some solutions for this, but solution was to get the number with completely different way and I wanna know if my code can be used for my needs.
Thanks for advices,
Adam

Comment: This question seems to be similar, hopefully it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534306/retrieve-the-call-number-in-my-android-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534306/retrieve-the-call-number-in-my-android-app/4534415#4534415

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please include permission in your application.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.show();
}
```

`CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` return null if its first call. So you should use `CALL_STATE_RINGING`.

Hopefully it will help you.