# retrieve the call number in my android APP

Tags: android, android-emulator

I would like to get the number call when i receive a call in my app.I would like to retrieve it and store it  somewhere.

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
    super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
```

.........

incomingNumber contains nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the permissions?

> Note that access to some telephony
>   information is permission-protected.
>   Your application won't receive updates
>   for protected information unless it
>   has the appropriate permissions
>   declared in its manifest file. Where
>   permissions apply, they are noted in
>   the appropriate LISTEN_ flags.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html

Comment: Yes I put suitable permission: the reason is that the application turns, i can emulate call. Am seeing the incoming number in logCat. The problem is that i can't put in a variable of my applicatiion

Comment: TX Shardul, i quitly have the same now, but my MyPhoneStateListener in not an inner class, but in a different file, does this cause problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Include following permissions in your application manifest as a child of `application`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Also include a receiver in manifest

```
<!-- SAMPLE APPLICATION IS NAME OF OUR APPLICATION -->
<receiver android:name="SampleApplication" 
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>

</receiver>
```

Create a class that extends `android.telephony.PhoneStateListener` and implement its `onCallStateChanged`

```
public class 
class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
  {
      public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
      {
          Log.d("SampleApp","Incoming call from: "+incomingNumber);
      }
  }
```

Now in you onCreate() call TelephonyManager and add this class as listener:

```
TelephonyManager myTelManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
MyPhoneStateListener myListner = new MyPhoneStateListener();
myTelManager.listen(myListner, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

You can check result in LogCat.

**EDIT :Complete class which stores response in variable:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public class SampleApp extends Activity{

private String incomingCallNumber="";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.rating);
    TelephonyManager myTelManager = 
(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    MyPhoneStateListener myListner = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    myTelManager.listen(myListner, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);


}
class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
  public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
  {
     SampleApp.this.incomingCallNumber=incomingNumber;
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Okay tx, the number is in the log, do you know how can retreieve it from log and put in variable.